# Custom subdomain on Route 53 pointing to cloudfront distribution and s3 static website not working

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-route53, amazon-cloudfront

I'm trying to configure a custom domain name ("test.example.com") transferred to Route 53, pointing towards an S3 static website bucket ("test.example.com"), through the use of a cloudfront distribution ("1111.cloudfront.net") (for the record, I couldn't point the domain toward the S3 bucket directly either). I've got the following settings;

**Route 53 record sets:**

- A test.example.com (alias = yes) pointing towards: 1111.cloudfront.net
- AAAA test.example.com (alias = yes) pointing towards: 1111.cloudfront.net

**Cloudfront distribution:**

- Alternate Domain Names (CNAMEs): test.example.com
- IPv6: enabled
- Delivery method: web
- Domain Name: 1111.cloudfront.net
- SSL certificate: *.example.com (registered in us-east-1, I've got a
  similar one in eu-north-1)
- Origin: test.example.com.s3.amazonaws.com

**Certificate manager:**

- Domain name: *.example.com
- Additional names: example.com
- Status: issued

**The following works:**

http://test.example.com.s3-website.eu-north-1.amazonaws.com

http://1111.cloudfront.com

https://1111.cloudfront.com

**The following does *not* work:**

http://test.example.com

https://test.example.com

I can't see what I'm missing?

Comment: *"does not work"* is pretty vague.  What happens when you try?

Comment: Yes, sorry. I get "server not found" as if I've never added the test.example.com records in route53. I've tried to follow:
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/Route53/latest/DeveloperGuide/RoutingToS3Bucket.html
and 
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudFront/latest/DeveloperGuide/cnames-and-https-procedures.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently DNSSEC was activated on the domain. Route 53 does not support DNSSEC. It was a transferred domain, so I could delete the public keys (you can't add, but you can delete keys created with the previous DNS service).

Answer (score 0):

Step 1 :Set Redirection for this --> http://test.example.com to http://1111.cloudfront.co
Step 2 :Set Url Masking for this --> http://1111.cloudfront.com (Coding) to actual website

URL Masking Link: https://www.brontobytes.com/knowledgebase/202/htaccess-URL-Masking-Examples.html?language=english&currency=7

I think you explained the in complex form kindly let us know actual content to be displayed (Source) and other pointing urls.